# Save As Dailog is not poping up

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

When I parse <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> command through selenium to open a save as dialog in latest version of chrome browser (i.e. 78) then it is blocking my save as dialog to appear.

But this problem doesn't occur in older chrome browser versions (i.e. 74).

So please suggest me with any solution.

Answer (score 0):

It is working fine in version 78 as well. just put a delay before pressing enter

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_S);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_S);
robot.delay(3000);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```